# Data lost with last version of react-native and AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, expo, redux-persist

When I try to update my application (android/ios) with react-native and expo my data is lost and i don't know why :

old version :

"react-native": "0.51.0",
"redux-persist": "4.8.2",

new version :

"redux-persist": "4.8.2",
"react-native": "~0.61.5",
"expo": "^37.0.12",

Build with expo for the newer version

How I persist the data. The code hasn't changed between versions.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    persistStore(
      store,
      {
        storage: AsyncStorage,
        whitelist: ['data', 'data2' ],
        transforms: [
          createTransform(
            state => state,
            state => ({
              ...state,
              infosOpened: false,
            }),
            {
              whitelist: 'app',
            }
          ),
        ],
      },
      () => {
        setRehydrated(true)
      }
    )
  }, [])
```

AsyncStorage is imported from react-native and I keep react-native with expo. @react-native-community/async-storage isn't compatible.

As what I saw inside the older version data is persisted with SQLlite format 3 inside "data user". Data appears to be always here with the newer version but it is no longer recovered.

I don't know if there is some braking changes react-native  from version 51 to 61. I see nothing inside github release tags.

Edit1: OK so it seems that the problem is that RN use RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1 folder and expo RCTAsyncLocalStorage. How I can fix that with the easiest way for IOS and Android ? Is it better to eject expo app or to add migration code ?

Edit2: Finally I opted for an RN version with react-native-unimodules like that I have no problem with path storage and I can use some dependencies from expo. (https://blog.expo.io/you-can-now-use-expo-apis-in-any-react-native-app-7c3a93041331)

Maybe the solution under works... I didn't test it

Another possible solution here. I didn't test it too :

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8220#issuecomment-656300244

Comment: My data is lost too. Do you find a solution ? Migration doesn't work for me, the "previous state" is empty. It's like a fresh install :(

Comment: Read Edit2. I have added some solutions maybe

Answer (score 1):

You can find the sample code for migration in the snippet. This snippet is migration from Expo to pure RN. You will only have to reverse migration.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

export default class WalletMigrate extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.migrateDataFromExpo();
  }

  migrationComplete() {
    console.log('Migration was successful. Exiting migration...')
    this.props.onComplete();
  }

  // Migrate Document directory from Expo
  async migrateDataFromExpo() {
    const expoDirectoryExists = await RNFS.exists(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/ExponentExperienceData');

    if (!expoDirectoryExists) {
        console.log('Expo data was previously migrated. Exiting migration...');
      this.props.onComplete();
      return;
    }
    try {
        await RNFS.unlink(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1')
        console.log('/RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1 has been deleted. Continuing...')
    } catch {
        console.log('/RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1 does not exist. Continuing...')
    }
    RNFS.copyFile(
      RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/ExponentExperienceData/%40USERNAME%2FAPPNAME/RCTAsyncLocalStorage',
      RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1',
    )
      .then(() => {
        RNFS.readDir(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1').then(files => {
          files.forEach(file => {
            if (file.name !== 'manifest.json') {
              RNFS.readFile(file.path).then(fileContents => {
                AsyncStorage.setItem('data', fileContents)
                .then(() => {
                  RNFS.unlink(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/ExponentExperienceData').then(() => this.migrationComplete());
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    console.log('An error was encountered when trying to delete /ExponentExperienceData. Exiting migration...');
                    this.props.onComplete();
                })
                .then(() => this.migrationComplete())
              });
            }
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('An error was encountered when trying to read the /RTCAsyncLocalStorage_V1 directory. Exiting migration...');
            console.log(error);
            this.props.onComplete();
        });
      })
      .catch(_error => this.props.onComplete());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignContent: 'center' }}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

WalletMigrate.propTypes = {
  onComplete: PropTypes.func,
};
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26553956)

Comment: @Ersoy Thanks for the warning. Edited and published again.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Finally I opted for an RN version with react-native-unimodules like that I have no problem with path storage. If  someone could tell that this code work to fixe issue with paths I will put as accepted the answer.